# Scraping dynamic table in R with POST

Tags: r, post, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [this table](http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/managed/alligator/harvest/data-export/) using R. So far, I've managed to get only 27 lines of it, using the code below. I would like to get all the entries back and, ideally, modify the request so that I can select certain years etc. Other questions on SO target slightly different situations, and I would like to keep this in the rvest-xml2-httr world, if possible.

```
url <- "http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/managed/alligator/harvest/data-export/"


view <- httr::POST(url) %>% 
  xml2::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("input[name='__VIEWSTATE']") %>% 
  rvest::html_attr("value")

param <- list(`__EVENTTARGET` =     "",
               `__EVENTARGUMENT` =  "",
               `__VIEWSTATE` = view,
               `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$RefreshButton` = "",
               `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_Year` = "",
               `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_AreaNumber` = "",
               `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_AreaName` =   "",
               `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox` = "10000",
               `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState` = "",
               `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_rfltMenu_ClientState` = "",
               `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_ClientState` =    "",
               `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` = "CA0B0334")

request <- httr::POST(url,
                       body = param,
                       encode = 'form') %>% 
  xml2::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_table(fill = T)

tib <- request[[1]]

> dim(tib)
[1] 27  9
```

Comment: Since you're submitting a form with `POST`, would it be easier to grab the CSV by using the `...$ExportToCsvButton` input? It'd be a whole lot faster to have them give you a structured CSV than having you scraping it. (BTW: what is `view_state`?)

Comment: @r2evans Sure, it would! How could I use that, would you mind explaining? (`view_state` was a typo, fixed it now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table in question has a "Export to CSV" link:

[image: table/link image]

If you click on it, you get the 6.36MB CSV file directly, which is good. I'm assuming that you need/want to do this programmatically, so this worked for me:

### Steps to Programmatically *"Click Export-to-CSV"*

1. I'm using Firefox, but Chrome has a similar capability: Inspector. I opened it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>) and went to the "Network" tab.
2. Click on the "Export to CSV" button. You should see a new "POST" line in the inspector frame. When it's complete ...
3. Right-click on the "POST" line and select "Copy POST Data"; this provides:

   ```
   __EVENTTARGET
   __EVENTARGUMENT
   __VIEWSTATE=...
   ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ExportToCsvButton=+
   ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_Year
   ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_AreaNumber
   ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_AreaName
   ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox=20
   ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState
   ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_rfltMenu_ClientState
   ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_pageBody_pageBody_rightColumn_ctl01_AlligatorHarvestExport_6_RadGrid1_ClientState
   __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334
   ```

   (I replaced the long base64-string with "`...`".) The notable line is the fourth, ending in `$ExportToCsvButton=+`. This is the parameter you need to include in your POST data (`param`).
4. Using your code above up through *and including* defining `param`, continue with:

   ```
   param$`ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$pageBody$pageBody$rightColumn$ctl01$AlligatorHarvestExport_6$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ExportToCsvButton` <- "+"
   request <- httr::POST(url, body = param, encode = 'form')
   ```

You'll now have:

```
request
# Response [http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/managed/alligator/harvest/data-export/]
#   Date: 2017-06-01 18:09
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: text/csv; charset-UTF-8;
#   Size: 6.36 MB
# <U+FEFF>"Year","Area Number","Area Name","Carcass Size","Harvest Date","Location"
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","11 ft. 5 in.","09-22-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","9 ft. 0 in.","10-02-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","8 ft. 10 in.","10-06-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","8 ft. 0 in.","09-25-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","8 ft. 0 in.","10-07-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","8 ft. 0 in.","09-22-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","7 ft. 2 in.","09-21-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","7 ft. 1 in.","09-21-2000",""
# "2000","101","LAKE PIERCE","6 ft. 11 in.","09-25-2000",""
# ...
```

Side note: the website starts the file with `<U+FEFF>`, a unicode character. This throws off `read.csv` and gives you a column name of `X.U.FEFF.Year`, is entirely cosmetic.

### Saving to File

If you don't care about the suggested filename, you can simply do

```
write(as.character(request), file="quux.csv")
```

If you want to use the filename the website suggests for it, you can find it with:

```
httr::headers(request)$`content-disposition`
# [1] "inline;filename=\"FWCAlligatorHarvestData.csv\""
```

Parsing that should be straight-forward.

### Immediate Consumption

If you don't want/need to save to an intermediate file, you can always consume it immediately:

```
head(read.csv(textConnection(as.character(request))))
# Invalid encoding : defaulting to UTF-8.
#   X.U.FEFF.Year Area.Number   Area.Name Carcass.Size Harvest.Date Location
# 1          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE 11 ft. 5 in.   09-22-2000         
# 2          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE  9 ft. 0 in.   10-02-2000         
# 3          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE 8 ft. 10 in.   10-06-2000         
# 4          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE  8 ft. 0 in.   09-25-2000         
# 5          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE  8 ft. 0 in.   10-07-2000         
# 6          2000         101 LAKE PIERCE  8 ft. 0 in.   09-22-2000
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you! I had been using RSelenium for this type of thing, but I was never happy with the process. This is much better. Thank you for the clear tutorial.

Comment: I was spring-loaded to recommend `RSelenium` based on the possibility of javascript-based data-loading. The process is not without some strife, and I agree that whenever possible it's likely better (more resilient) to use `rvest` or `httr` to get the data. I'm glad the "tutorial" format worked well for you, I often find it useful to provide some "why and how" in addition to the stark "what".