# Rvest not seeing xpath in website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to [scrape this website](http://www.diversitydatakids.org/data/ranking/10/population-under-age-18-number-by-raceethnicity#loct=4&loc=3716&tf=4&ch=1,2,3,4,5,6,7) using the rvest package in R. I have done it successfully with several other website but this one doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why.

I copied the xpath from inside chrome's inspector tool, but when i specify it in the rvest script it shows that it doesn't exist. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the table is generated and not static?

appreciate the help!

```
library(rvest)
library (tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

a<-read_html("http://www.diversitydatakids.org/data/profile/217/benton-county#ind=10,12,15,17,13,20,19,21,24,2,22,4,34,35,116,117,123,99,100,127,128,129,199,201")
a<-html_node(a, xpath="//*[@id='indicator10']")
a<-html_table(a)
a
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Most likely you will need to use `httr::POST` with the xml2 package. Here's an example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313122/scraping-dynamic-table-in-r-with-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313122/scraping-dynamic-table-in-r-with-post)

Comment: edited the post to include the code

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, yes, you are unable to get it because is being generated dynamically. In these cases, it's better to use the `RSelenium` library:

```
#Loading libraries
library(rvest) # to read the html
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of the website

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- "http://www.diversitydatakids.org/data/profile/217/benton-county#ind=10,12,15,17,13,20,19,21,24,2,22,4,34,35,116,117,123,99,100,127,128,129,199,201"

# go to website
remDr$navigate(url)

# get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

# get the element you are looking for
a <-html_node(html_obj, xpath="//*[@id='indicator10']")
```

I guess that you are trying to get the first table. In that case, maybe it's better to just get the table with `read_table`:

```
# get the table with the indicator10 id
indicator10_table <-html_node(html_obj, "#indicator10 table") %>% html_table()
```

I'm using the CSS selector this time instead of the XPath.

Hope it helps! Happy scraping!