# How do I scrape dynamic table in R with doPostBack?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm looking to extract the content of a table from a website into a list or `df`  The website is: https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0

The content of the full table looks to be navigated using:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ctl05
javascript:__doPostBack('ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ctl06
```

The list continues to return rows spread across 83 pages.  I'm looking for an `rvest` solution that can scrape the data for me.  I'm hoping someone can give me a little step by step instruction so that I can benefit from learning the "how" part of it.

The alternative `rvest` solution that I found looks to be simulating the "export to CSV" similar to this post :[Scraping dynamic table in R with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313122/scraping-dynamic-table-in-r-with-post).

I'd prefer not to use `rSelenium` or `phantomJS`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely use rvest, but it will be much more complicated. What you need to do is to monitor the network tab in developer tools while clicking the **export data** button. It will be a post request, and what you need to do is to replicate the post request with the headers and form data.

Or you can solve it using RSelenium in a couple of lines.

```
library(RSelenium)

rmDr <- rsDriver(port = 4444L)

client <- rmDr$client

url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer600&team=0&lg=all&players=0"

client$navigate(url)

export_buttom <- client$findElement(using = "css",value = "#ProjectionBoard1_cmdCSV")

export_buttom$clickElement()
```